# Laravel 5 Auth - What exactly is it?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I understand that the auth functions allows a user to login etc, but I wanted a confirmation on what exactly was happening in the background.

My guess is that it's just a cookie that holds the login details, correct?

Or is it only storing the `remember_token` and then automatically comparing that with what is stored in the users table?

So if I wanted to create an account edit page. Would I have to do anything like comparing the auth id with the users table id that the e-mail matches up with? Or is it handling all that automatically?

Comment: You can have a look at the `Auth` package files located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth`, especially the `Guard.php` file, to get a sense of what and how it's doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Auth is nothing but its class where already  all authentication methods or functions are written in laravel out of box.so you need  not required to write all that function which is relating to user login.for example to check user we simply use 
Auth::check();

but in laravel auth class they written like this

```
public function check()
    {
        return !is_null($this->user());
    }
```

in the same way for login attempt we are passing parameter to attempt method .Here also laravel built in function is there

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true)
    {
        $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

        $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
        // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
        // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
        if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
            if ($login) {
                $this->login($user, $remember);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here you are passing all credentials in array and remember password and all

Comment: I understand that, but if I do something like Auth::User()->id is that secure? Is the Auth User ID just being stored in a cookie? In which case wouldn't that be changable?

Comment: i think its secure .i don't think its store in cookie.its basically store in session.